# NoClassDefFoundError for dependencies when compiling executable jar with no build tools

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm trying to compile my Java program into an executable jar file, and I've tried following all the instructions in various places, but I'm encountering an issue.

#### Class Files

The first thing I do is compile everything to class files with this command.

```sh
javac -d ./build src/main/**/*.java -cp lib/main/commons-cli-1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar:lib/main/commons-io-2.8.0/commons-io-2.8.0.jar
```

This compiles all the `.java` files in `src/main` (I don't want to compile the tests of course) into a folder called `build`. It also sets the classpath to all the `.jar` files that the code depends on (Apache Commons CLI and Apache Commons IO).

#### Jar Files

The next step is to generate the `.jar` file. For this, I use the following command (after `cd ./build`).

```sh
jar cvfm ../bin/program.jar manifest.txt .
```

Here, `manifest.txt` is in the folder `build` and contains the following. (It ends with a trailing newline, as per the documentation dictates.)

```sh
Main-Class: cli.Cli
```

Here, `cli.Cli` refers to the class named `Cli` located in `src/main/cli/Cli.java` which contains the main method.

#### Running the Jar

Now I use the following command to try to run the produced `program.jar` file, but I get this error.

```sh
$ java -jar build/program.jar
Error: Unable to initialize main class cli.Cli
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
```

This error is referring to one of the import statements in `src/main/cli/Cli.java`, which is supposed to be in the same `.jar` file as all the other import statements. The IDE does recognise the import, but I'm not sure why I am unable to run the file. Here is an extract of my imports from `Cli.java`.

```java
package cli;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
// more imports...
```

#### Edit

I tried to change the manifest to contain a classpath, but that didn't seem to help at all. I tried the following two versions of the manifest.

Relative to `bin/` or `build/`:

```sh
Main-Class: cli.Cli
Class-Path: ../lib/main/commons-cli-1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar:../lib/main/commons-io-2.8.0/commons-io-2.8.0.jar
```

Relative to workspace folder (which is the current directory when I run the jar):

```sh
Main-Class: cli.Cli
Class-Path: lib/main/commons-cli-1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar:lib/main/commons-io-2.8.0/commons-io-2.8.0.jar
```

#### Edit 2

I changed my code to not use `ParseException` but then another of the imports caused the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the classpath in the manifest needed to be space-separated, with the paths to each jar relative to `bin/`, like so:

```sh
Main-Class: cli.Cli
Class-Path: ../lib/main/commons-cli-1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar ../lib/main/commons-io-2.8.0/io-2.8.0.jar program.jar
```